# Doctrine Multi checkbox in zend framework 2

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i want to create categorize multi checkbox in zend framework 2 form. Below is the picture that what i want to achieve.

[image]

I already displayed all checkboxes with the help of **DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox**. How can i categorize them into their related portion.

Below are my entities.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="permissions")
 */
class Permission implements PermissionInterface
{

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=true)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=false)
 */
protected $label;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApplicationFeatures", inversedBy="permissions")
 */
protected $applicationFeature;
}
```

The above entity present checkboxs. For category i create another entity and add foreign key to above entity to check which permission belong to with category. my another entity is

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="application_features")
 */
class ApplicationFeatures
{
/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30, unique=true)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Permission", mappedBy="applicationFeature")
 */
protected $permissions;
}
```

Comment: and with what exactly do you have trouble? getting the checkboxes render/validate or hydrate?

Comment: My problem is styling. I displayed all checkboxes but dont know how to display with categories  which are found in different table (entity)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it this way:
You have class Permission and class ApplicationFeatures.
Use only 1 class Permission with additional column - Parent.
When you print MultiCheckBoxes, your Banner Management, Pages Management, Menu Management will become checkboxes.

In your Controller edit form this way:

```
{
    $form->bind($Permission); 
    $list = SELECT ARRAY FROM DATABASE IN A FORM $result['id'] = $result;
    $element = $form->get('Permission');
    $myValueOptions = $element->getValueOptions();

    $newValueOptions = array();
    foreach($myValueOptions AS $key=>$myValueOption){
        $newValueOptions[$key] = $myValueOption;
        $newValueOptions[$key]['label_attributes'] = 
            array('style' => 'display:block; ');
        if($list[$myValueOption['value']]['isParent']==1){
            $newValueOptions[$key]['label_attributes']['style'] .=
                  'font-weight: bold;';
            $newValueOptions[$key]['attributes'] = array('class'=>'isParent');
        }
    }
    $element->setValueOptions(newValueOptions);
}
```

Now remove checkboxes at parent labels. At the end of your .phtml add script:

```
{

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".isParent" ).remove();
    });
</script>
}
```